# FontAwesome in SCSS/SASS showing squares

Tags: reactjs, sass, font-awesome, scss-mixins

This have been asked several times but I can't seem to get an updated answer.

I've been trying to load a fontawesome icon in my .scss and I specifically followed this instruction https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/sass but I'm still just getting squares.

Here are my codes

**_fontawesome.scss**

```
@import './scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import './scss/solid.scss';

.user {
  @extend %fa-icon;
  @extend .fas;

  &:before {
    content: fa-content($fa-var-user);
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
<span className="user" />
```

**_variables.scss**

```
$fa-font-path:         "../webfonts" !default;
```

---

**My directory**

```
public/
     fontawesome/
          scss/
          webfonts/
          _fontawesome.scss
```

If it helps, I'm using this for react and I can perfectly use FontAwesome as a component using npm, but I have this case where I need to use it in the scss.

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how you don't use the font awesome CDN ? it's works perfectly for me.
And it would keep you from getting bored with it :(

something like that to your  and it's works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
```

I'll take a closer look at your problem, but tomorrow because it's to late :p

Comment: hi! thanks for the response. but is there a way to use it for .scss instead? it's what i've been using instead

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.